# How do I save a collection with another name with mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a mongoengine schema like this:

```
class Page(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    meta = {"db_alias":"page", "collection":"page_detail"}
```

as you can see, my collection will be save with name "page_detail".

so my problem is this:

I have data in my database already, but some record is useless, so I need to filter them. Now, I want to filter them and save the filtered data in another collection with this schema, so I have any choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework with [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator, which will store the result of your query into a new collection specified in the `$out`.

```
db.yourOldCollection.aggregate([
                                  <your filetring pipeline, e.g. $match>,
                                  {$out: "yourNewCollection"}
                              ])
```